# Is it possible to put images as a horizontal pinterest?

Tags: css, image, drupal, pinterest

I have a lot of images but I wish to put these like a follow image:

[image]

And each image (on click) displays a modal with custom text.

Actually I use Drupal 7.
Sorry for my english. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible in pure css unless you add a wrapper around columns of images. The most-used solution for this problem is [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com).